# Leaving Classloader open after first use

Tags: java, classloader

I am creating a URLClassloader to load some jars. Each jar gets loaded correctly from a different classloader and each jar contains a class with a method run(). Now the body of this run() can create an anonymous inner class in it. However, because i created my URLClassloader in a try-with-resources block it gets autoclosed and at run time when it tries to load the anonymous inner class it throws a NoClassDefFoundError because the classloader is already closed.

Now my question is, *what is the normal practice for these situations?* is it ok to leave the classloader open so that when later it needs to load something else, it can? is there a way to reopen a closed classloader?
If I leave the classloader open, the compiler gives me warnings about potential resource leaks <del>so I have a feeling this is like streams where you are not supposed to leave them open indefinitely</del>. However because of the nature of classloaders, if it's not the same classloader that loads the anonymous class, it cannot be used in the outer class

here is the code where the classloader is created

```
public Player(File codePath) throws PlayerException {

   try (URLClassLoader loader = new URLClassLoader(new URL[] { codePath.toURI().toURL() })) {

   //load class from Jar where run() method creates anonymous class that comes in the jar too


   } catch (ClassCastException | IOException | ClassNotFoundException | InstantiationException
| IllegalAccessException | IllegalArgumentException | InvocationTargetException
| SecurityException exc) {
throw new PlayerException("Error loading player's code", exc);

}
```

Comment: Note that "closing" the class loader is not the same as deleting it.  The loader will still exist as long any class loaded with it is still referenced anywhere.  "Closing" it simply reclaims the resources used to access the class path.  If you create a lot of class loaders then these resources can add up (in particular the process open file handle limit).  If only a few it's no big deal.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The life time of a class loader should be at least the life time of the instances of the classes loaded with it. As long as they and their classes are not eligible for garbage collection neither is their class loader. And should they need to load additional code or resources you need the class loader open.

So when you're done with a player, that's the time when you should close the class loader.

Comment: do you have any idea on the cost of leaving, say 10 classloaders open for the whole game basically? right now i do close them when a player dies but that happens after a while. I want to know if this is something i should be worried about

Comment: Well, the class loader itself won't be garbage collected until the player is garbage collected. So we can ignore that cost. The only additional cost are the open file descriptors. I don't know how many JARs you have per player but if it's just one then that's just one file descriptor per player.

Comment: While the life of the class loader should be (and in fact WILL be) at least the life of the loaded classes, this does not mean that the paths used to load classes must remain open.  In general the loader should be "closed" when it's known that no more classes will be loaded through it.

Comment: Yes, but it's hard to know that. Since class loading is dynamic and the objects are still used you can't be sure that no additional classes or resources will have to be loaded in the future.

Answer (score 0):

Rather than creating a new classloader for each player, you could use a Factory Pattern (or something similar):

```
URLClassLoader loader = PlayerClassLoaderFactory.getInstance().getClassLoader(codePath.toURI())
```

where the factory maintains the references to the classloaders (so the classes are not orphaned).  Then you have the ability to "shutdown" the factory if needed to close the classloaders.

Comment: that's a good suggestion but it doesn't answer my question since the problem of whether the classloader should be closed at the end of loading the player or kept open for the whole game would still need to be answered. What I actually did was i just made the local variable a class member since the classloader is a property of the player, but i will think about making it a factory

Comment: If in the course of initialization you end up loading all the classes you need into permgen, then you can close it, since those classes will still be accessible after closing.  However, if that is not the case, then you should keep it open in case additional classes are loaded (as a result of user actions for example)